# When using Joi with Hapi, how does one setup a require on one key but allow any and all other keys?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, hapi.js

I'm trying to write a *Joi* validation for a JSON object coming into a *Hapi* handler. So far the code looks like this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/converge',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        consociator.consociate(request.payload)
            .then (function (result) {
                reply (200, result);
            });
    },
    config: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                value: Joi.object().required().keys({ knownid: Joi.object() })
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

You can see the *Joi* object validation so far in the config: validate: code section above. The JSON coming in looks like this.

```
"key": '06e5140d-fa4e-4758-8d9d-e707bd19880d-testA',
"value": {
    "ids_lot_args": {
        "this_id": "stuff",
        "otherThign": "more data"
    },
    "peripheral_data": 'Sample peripheral data of any sort'
}
```

In this JSON above the key and value at the root of the object are required, and the section called `ids_lot_args` is required. The section that starts with peripheral_data could be there or not, or could be any other JSON payload. It doesn't matter, only key and value at the root level and `ids_lot_args` inside the value are required.

So far, I'm stumbling through trying to get the *Joi* validation to work. 
**Any ideas on how this should be setup?** The code repo for Joi is located at https://github.com/hapijs/joi if one wants to check it out. I've been trying the allow all functions on objects to no avail so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to call the [`unknown()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#objectunknownallow) function on the `value` object:

```
var schema = Joi.object({
  key: Joi.string().required(),
  value: Joi.object({
    ids_lot_args: Joi.object().required()
  }).unknown().required()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "allowUnknown" parameter:

```
validate : {
  options : {
    allowUnknown: true
  },
  headers : {
  ...
  },
  params : {
  ...
  },
  payload : {
  ...
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try using Joi.any()

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/converge',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        consociator.consociate(request.payload)
            .then (function (result) {
                reply (200, result);
            });
    },
    config: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                key: Joi.string().required(),
                value: Joi.object({
                  ids_lot_args: Joi.object().required(),
                  peripheral_data: Joi.any()
                })
            } 
        }
    }});
```